# Closing script causes false XSS error on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, tabs, xss

We have a platform which is working together with other companies, thouse companies sites get opend in a tab with

```
 window.open('#','ociCallWindow','width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,copyhistory=no');
```

Now  this opens a site which posts data back to a handler to out side via a javascript autosubmit form.
This handler generates a page which should close the page and redirect the ser somwhere else on our system.

Well ther IE starts to behave lake douche he is and yells a XSS attack i have to disable the xss to  get it to work.  just like it is described on 
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/169672-internet-explorer-cross-site-scripting-xss-filter-turn-off.html
Then all works ok.

But i have somhow to circumvent the xss alert.

Here is the code which is genarated with our site:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dtagent55_bejnp3_5160.js" data-dtconfig="rid=RID_895225973|rpid=315099290|domain=eprocure.at|tp=500,50,0|bandwidth=300"></script><script type="text/javascript">var NREUMQ=NREUMQ||[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="js/catalog.js"></script>
<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="css/catalog-mondi.css"><title>TESTSYSTEM: mondizone</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/catalog.min.js?rnd=2.69.2"></script>
</head>

            <body class='backgrd' leftmargin='0' topmargin='0' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' text='#000000' link='#424E91' vlink='#7979BD' alink='#336633'>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Die Artikel wurden erfolgreich in Ihren Warenkorb übernommen. <br />Falls dieses Fenster nicht automatisch geschlossen wird, können Sie dieses Fenster jetzt schließen.                 </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                    if (opener || window.opener || self.opener) {
                        var myopener = getOpener();

                        myopener.document.dispmenu.target = "";

                                            myopener.document.dispmenu.xxxxxx_errors.value = '{serialized object... ye i know...}';
                                        myopener.document.dispmenu.dxxx.value = 'cart' ;
                        myopener.document.dispmenu.submit();
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Das Elternfenster wurde bereits geschlossen oder es kann nicht darauf zugegriffen werden. Die Artikel wurden trotzdem übernommen.');
                    }
                    window.close();
                                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">if(!NREUMQ.f){NREUMQ.f=function(){NREUMQ.push(["load",new Date().getTime()]);var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript";e.async=true;e.src="https://d1ros97qkrwjf5.cloudfront.net/42/eum/rum.js";document.body.appendChild(e);if(NREUMQ.a)NREUMQ.a();};NREUMQ.a=window.onload;window.onload=NREUMQ.f;};NREUMQ.push(["nrf2","beacon-1.newrelic.com","62a9b17b88",1115503,"MgZbNUAFCBVQVxFcCwtMbBNbSwUHRRsKVg0XBk0UQApIFllACFk=",0,1668,new Date().getTime()]);</script>
</body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gues il share my insigts on this.

While i didnt make any explicit progress on it i figured out a general problem which causes this to ocure.

In my case we did a OCI call to a externall site, after painstacking fidling with the data we figured out that our site traficking tool is responsible. New relic is a server sided plugin which injects a crosssite scripting script in all of your http calls. The worst is that it is usually not visible on the end of a page load. Also the problem arisses when the page wich causes the page close has its own tracking tools. In generall you HAVE to use Fiddler2 to cach thouse damn things! debuggint tools tend to miss this code, no idea why.